# WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl always fails with error code 12180 (ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, proxy, network-programming

I'm trying get the proxy settings for my computer automatically.
I've set up a local server and I've uploaded a .pac file (which I can access from my browser) and I've set the link to it in the Internet Explorer connection settings, in the "address" field and checked "Use automatic configuration script".

My code is the following:

```
int main()
{
    LPWSTR str = NULL;
    if (!WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl(WINHTTP_AUTO_DETECT_TYPE_DHCP | WINHTTP_AUTO_DETECT_TYPE_DNS_A, &str))
    {
        printf("%d\n", GetLastError());
    }

    if(str)
        GlobalFree(str);
    return 0;
}
```

The function always fails and GetLastError returns 12180 (ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120622/errorwinhttpautodetectionfailed, they say that this happens if you have direct connection (no proxy). So maybe your code is not wrong, it's just that you haven't really setup the proxy correctly.

Comment: Indeed, you have to set some settings in the DNS. After that it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/120622/errorwinhttpautodetectionfailed:

> This error message is not necessarily a problem and can be ignored if you are using direct connection. you get this error if you are having direct connection. to check that and get more info, you can use the following commands:
>   cd windows\system32
>   netsh winhttp help
>   — answered 4 years ago by Nick G

From your comment I gather that this was indeed the reason you were getting this error, so I'm posting it as an answer.